# What are the dangers with using "--assume-yes" with apt-get?

Tags: linux, bash, apt

While making some improvements to my `.bashrc` file, I [noticed](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/use-command-aliases-for-lazy-terminal-installing-purging-searching/) a frequently used alias:

```
alias install='sudo apt-get -y install'
```

I wasn't familiar with the `-y` (aka `--assume-yes` or `--yes`) option with `apt-get`, which I learned automatically says "Yes" to any prompt that comes up with `apt-get`.

This sounds handy. What's the catch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could inadvertently to agree to download and install a *huge* set of dependencies (e.g. if you want to install a KDE program on a machine where no KDE is installed).

Comment: You could also accidentally upgrade packaages you don't want to.  Such as if you had custom configured a package where the package install script might break your changes.

Comment: @Kerrek SB and @bigendian - GOOD call... Thanks for mentioning these scenarios. I'll play it safe and leave out the `-y` in my aliasing.